# Why does my pointer to struct forget strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

In my main functions I have two players which are represented by structs with data, including names. When in another source file I create a pointer to these structures, I am unable to access the name strings, whereas the rest of the data is fine.

```
//In pokemonList.c
typedef struct{

    char name[20];
    int level;
    int health;
    int type;
    int type2;


    int fainted;


    int moves[4];

    //stats
    int hp;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    int spAttack;
    int spDefense;
    int speed;

    int attackStage;
    int defenseStage;
    int spAttackStage;
    int spDefenseStage;
    int speedStage;

    int spriteNo;

}Pokemon;

Pokemon summon(Pokemon pokemon, int level){
    pokemon.level = level;
    pokemon.health = (int)((((2.0 * (double)pokemon.hp) + 31.0) * (double)level)/100.0) + (double)level + 10.0;
    pokemon.attack = levelUp(pokemon.attack, pokemon.level);
    pokemon.defense = levelUp(pokemon.defense, pokemon.level);
    return pokemon;
}

//In main.c
player1 = summon(venusaur, 50);
player2 = summon(blastoise, 100);

initialiseGUI(&player1, &player2);

//In video.c

void initialiseGUI(Pokemon *p1, Pokemon *p2){

    strcpy(player1name, p1->name);
    strcpy(player2name, p2->name);
    printf("p1->name: %s\n", p1->name);
    player1 = p1;
    player2 = p2;

    printf("p1->name: %s\nplayer1->name: %s\n", p1->name, player1->name);
}
```

I expected the output of this to be:

```
p1->name: Venusaur

p1->name: Venusaur

player1->name: Venusaur
```

Actual output:

```
p1->name: Venusaur

p1->name:

player1->name:
```

all the other data in the struct is accessible from player1->....

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

How are `venusaur` and `blastoise` created? How are their names set?

Comment: Show declaration of `player1`.  Best: [mcve]

Comment: Too much code missing...

Comment: You have a `player1` in main. You have a `player1` in video.c. Are they the same variable? BTW: Don't use global variables...

Answer (score 2):

`player1` must be of type `Pokemon` as it gets its value from the function `summon` that return a `Pokemon`

`p1` is of type `Pokemon *` (aka Pokemon pointer)

and you do `player1 = p1;`

In other words - you assign a "Pokemon pointer" to a "Pokemon" which is invalid.

What seems to happen is that you overwrite part of the string `name` with the pointer variable and thereby destroy the string value.